# Filter Date in MongoDB Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the operator Schema on my codes:

```
const operatorSchema = new Schema({
    operatorName: {
        type: String
    },

    users:[{
        email:String,
        payment:Number,
        paymentsData: Date,
        product: String,

      }],


});
```

I want to filter the user's paymentData date by month within a specific operator.

Date keep this format in DB: `2022-07-26T10:45:34.296+00:00`

I'm trying like this:

```
async function getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth(operatorName, month){
    // const operator = await Operators.findOne({operatorName});
    // var myDate = Date.now()

    Operators.find( { $and: [ { operatorName: operatorName },  { paymentsData: { $gte: new Date(2022, 7, 21),$lt: new Date(2022, 7, 25)  }} ] },function (err, docs) {    // Operators.find({operatorName: operatorName, paymentsData: {$gte: Date(2022,7,21)}}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else {
            docs.forEach(function(data){ 
            console.log(data)
             })
            // res.render('total_earns_operator_tables', { operators: docs });
        } 
      }); 




}
```

But I get all dates not between (2022, 7, 21) and (2022, 7, 25) in related operatorName.

paymentsData in users array so also I try with this but I get errors when I use like this:

```
Operators.find( { $and: [ { operatorName: operatorName },  {users: { paymentsData: { $gte: new Date(2022, 7, 21),$lt: new Date(2022, 7, 25)  }}} ] },function (err, docs) {    // Operators.find({operatorName: operatorName, paymentsData: {$gte: Date(2022,7,21)}}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else {
        docs.forEach(function(data){ 
        console.log(data)
         })
        // res.render('total_earns_operator_tables', { operators: docs });
    } 
  });
```

How can I do this ?

**EDIT**

I try with this according to suggestion but it returns anything:

```
   Operators.aggregate([
        { $match: { operatorName: operatorName}},
        { $unwind: '$users'},
        { $match: {'users.paymentsData': 
            { $gte: new Date(2022, 7, 21),$lt: new Date(2022, 7, 25) }
        }
       }]
    ,function (err, docs) {    // Operators.find({operatorName: operatorName, paymentsData: {$gte: Date(2022,7,21)}}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else {
            docs.forEach(function(data){ 
            console.log(data)
             })
            // res.render('total_earns_operator_tables', { operators: docs });
        } 
      });
```

Comment: Is there any suggestion for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate function like this,

```
   Operators.aggregate(
    { $match: { operatorName: operatorName)}},
    { $unwind: '$users'},
    { $match: {'users.paymentsData': {
        { $gte: new Date(2022, 7, 21),$lt: new Date(2022, 7, 25) }
      }
    }
   })
```

Comment: I added your suggestion in my topic but it doesnt return anydata although I get lots of data

Comment: do you have any suggestion ?